# Xamarin Forms page not showing (iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have made a test application in Xamarin.Forms with 2 pages. The main page is the start of the stack on which I want to put a login page. After PushModalAsync the login page does not show.

Enclosed I have a zip file of the test project.

[TestProject](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/6eb33ccbdf98aabc0949a530eb11ade320141204103631/93607607f69815bd0e6a7492f820b91020141204103631/42311b)

```
    public static async void StartLogin()
    {

        Button btnLogin = new Button();
        btnLogin.Text = "Login";
        btnLogin.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        btnLogin.TextColor = Color.White;

        ContentPage _loginPage = new ContentPage
                                 {
                                         Title = "Login",
                                         Content = new StackLayout
                                                   {
                                                           Spacing = 20,
                                                           Padding = 50,
                                                           VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                                           Children =
                                                           {

                                                                   btnLogin,
                                                           }
                                                   }
                                 };
        _loginPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;


        await Navigation.PushAsync(_loginPage);

    }
```

Comment: StartLogin() is called in the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Navigation.PushAsync(_loginPage););
```

Because Navigation is a UI operation it must be executed on the UI thread. If you leave it as it is nothing will happen as it hasn't been executed on the UI thread. Using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` should fix that

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists.